# Can you use the power fusion multiple times?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

Can you use the power fusion and then use it again on another willing target?

From [the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/fusion.htm):

> You and another willing, corporeal, living creature of the same or smaller size fuse into one being.

I can't even understand how you could think this cannot be chained. The person arguing this said the power says "you and one willing creature" and seems to be presupposing it says "you and one willing creature only"

Comment: It's polite to tell folks when you've crossposted elsewhere a question—like [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?527767-Simple-RAW-Thread-for-3-5-33-Doesn-t-everything-popular-die-when-33/page15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. [From the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/fusion.htm):

> You and another willing, corporeal, living creature of the same or smaller size fuse into one being. As the manifester, you control the actions of the fused being.

The manifester can continue to act, and retains their identity as "You".

> The fused being knows all the powers you and the other creature know, has the sum of your and the other creature’s power points

You can manifest powers as normal with some augmentations, including this one.

There is no text forbidding double-*fusion*, whereas there is for stacking with *fission*:

> You cannot use fission on a fused being.

Since all effects of *fusion* can be applied as-is to a manifester that is already fused, and since the manifester is rather different from when they first manifested *fusion*, double-*fusion* would seem to be a good candidate for exceptions to same-effect cancelling:

> The same spell can sometimes produce varying effects if applied to the same recipient more than once. Usually the last spell in the series trumps the others. None of the previous spells are actually removed or dispelled, but their effects become irrelevant while the final spell in the series lasts.

It wouldn't make sense to avoid "removing" a previous manifestation of *fusion* if the effects are cancelled out — where would the previously merged creature go?

Comment: Like multiple *polymorph* spells applied to the same creature, would the last *fusion* render any earlier *fusions* irrelevant (as per Same Effect with Differing Results on *PH* 72)?

Comment: @HeyICanChan: I don't think so, and it wouldn't seem to make much sense to have it do so. That rule is not phrased absolutely, so this is one of the better exception cases for it.

Comment: I dunno. It seems like *only the last one counts* prevents a lot of shenanigans possible with the power. That, *and* the spell doesn't *say* that its effects are cumulative with subsequent uses. I think the answer's sound, but I also think there's room enough for the DM to rule the other way. (I also don't like the comment from the asker that an *only* is necessary to distinguish between effects that can only occur once and those that can occur multiple times—that rubs me wrong as writer and rules-reader.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan: I agree that the asker's reasoning is suspect. I think my last paragraph here could use some polishing to clarify more, but right now I can't think how to do that.

Comment: A direct comparison to *polymorph* might be useful. I mean, if a wizard casts *polymorph* to assume squirrel form then casts *polymorph* again (somehow) to assume hill giant form without first ending the *polymorph* into squirrel form, where does the squirrel form go?

Comment: In the giant's belly.

Comment: @TuggyNE "we can understand how to go about stacking this spell with itself" is not a good justification for bypassing the stacking rules.  Trivial example there would be say....letting Bear's Endurance self-stack.  The stacking rules are there to prevent a balance issue, not to prevent a compile issue.

Comment: On polymorph it seems to fall under the second effect being make irrelevant. Polymorph specifically reverts all the effects of the first one. If fusion was meant to be a one time only then it would include language similar to fission.

Comment: @godskook my question is does it stack per raw, not *should* it stack based on rules as intended for balance purposes.

Comment: @mlanier my statement is not about non-RAW, its about how to *read* RAW.  TuggyNE was proposing that the reason he could ignore a piece of RAW was X, and I was saying that X is not a valid reason to ignore that piece of RAW.

Comment: @godskook: My argument does not depend primarily on it being *theoretically possible* to stack, but on it being *possible* to stack and *difficult to imagine how a non-stacking interpretation would function*.